# How can I stack two Pandas dataframes with different columns and a few similar observations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Here's the thing, I have two dataframes. The first dataframe has 5 columns and the seconde has 10 columns. Additionally, there are a few observations that appears in both dataframes and I wanted to keep only those that appears in the second one.

This would be the first dataframe:

```
id        month        year        purchase         category
A0        2            2020        100              clothes
A0        3            2020        40               food
A9        2            2020        50               food
A9        3            2020        90               food
A9        4            2020        150              clothes
A9        5            2020        160              clothes
B1        2            2021        110              game
B1        3            2021        100              game
.
.
.
```

And this would be the second dataframe:

```
id        month        year        purchase         category    col_1 ...   col_n
A0        2            2020        100              clothes     10    ...   ABC
A9        4            2020        150              clothes     20    ...   DDD
A9        5            2020        160              clothes     10    ...   ACD
B1        2            2021        110              game        15    ...   EEE
.
.
.
```

I wanted to get the two dataframes together, stacked, but when there is an observation with all five columns equal, we would only consider the observation from the second dataframe, so I can keep all columns fullfilled.

This would be the desired output:

```
id        month        year        purchase         category    col_1  ... col_n
A0        2            2020        100              clothes     10     ... ABC
A0        3            2020        40               food        NaN    ... NaN
A9        2            2020        50               food        NaN    ... NaN
A9        3            2020        90               food        NaN    ... NaN
A9        4            2020        150              clothes     20     ... DDD
A9        5            2020        160              clothes     10     ... ACD
B1        2            2021        110              game        15     ... EEE
B1        3            2021        100              game        NaN    ... NaN
.
.
.
```

I thought about using pandasql, so I would make several subqueries. But maybe there is a Pandas solution, shorter and faster.

Comment: Please add your expected output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost definitely some way to do this in one line but this approach should still do the trick:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A0', 'A0', 'A9'],
                    'month': [2, 3, 2],
                    'purchase': [100, 40, 50],
                    'category': ['clothes', 'food', 'food']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A0', 'A0', 'A9'],
                    'month': [2, 3, 4],
                    'purchase': [100, 40, 50],
                    'category': ['clothes', 'food', 'food'],
                    'something else': ['foo', 'blah', 'blerg']})
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = 'outer')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = df1.columns)
```

This will then give:

|  | id | month | purchase | category | something else |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A0 | 2 | 100 | clothes | foo |
| 1 | A0 | 3 | 40 | food | blah |
| 2 | A9 | 4 | 50 | food | blerg |
| 3 | A9 | 2 | 50 | food | NaN |